# Android room rawquery issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I want to implement Android Room persistence.
This is my DAO interface.

```
@Dao
interface FoodDao {

    /**
     * Returns all data in table for Paging
     *
     * @param query a dynamic SQL query
     */
    @RawQuery
    fun getAll(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): DataSource.Factory<Int, Food>
}
```

For some reason, I have this compile error:

error: Observable query return type (LiveData, Flowable, DataSource, DataSourceFactory etc) can only be used with SELECT queries that directly or indirectly (via @Relation, for example) access at least one table. For @RawQuery, you should specify the list of tables to be observed via the observedEntities field.
public abstract androidx.paging.DataSource.Factory<java.lang.Integer, com.google.developers.teacup.data.Tea> getAll(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull

Answer (score 19):

You have to specify observed entity:

@RawQuery(observedEntities = [Food::class])

See for more: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RawQuery#observedEntities()